# Cypress capture href string to use in a later request

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to capture a string representation of a generated href and use it in a later page that I have navigated to.

I have tried capturing the anchor using cy.get(), cy.find() etc so I can click() it later but obviously that link goes stale after navigating away from the page. I tried chaining into then(), I also tried using .getAttribute(), but I get an object back not a string.

I am struggling to find a way to get to the underlying values of the cypress objects, even calling cy.document() returns a cypress representation instead of what intuitively I’d have guessed was *THE* DOM document. Clearly I have no idea what Cypress is doing, or much of a clue about the opinions of the framework other than I get the feeling that I am trying to implement some Cypress anti pattern.

I don’t really care how, but I would like to capture the generated url that I can locate in an anchor tags href in the page. Please can someone suggest how I could capture the string value so that I might be able to use it in a cy.request() later?

I can post some examples later when I am at my computer if needed, but I suspect my description is sufficient, but please let me know otherwise.

Example:

```
describe('Test Description', function () {

  var capturedHref = "";

  before(function() {
    // can set the name here, it becomes the context text on an anchor
    generateLinkViaAppFunctionality();

    // find by the content text taken from name on link generation
    capturedHref = <href from link>
  }

  it('Test', function() {
    cy.visit('some app page');
    doStuff();

    cy.visit(capturedHref);
  })
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but what you describe as 'cypress representation' may be described as 'jquery repesentation' as this is used under the hood - in which case taking the first index, e.g `result[0]` may give you the element itself. Difficult to understand more until you post the full example.

Comment: @eric99 thanks for your reply, on my way into work will update my question with code example, and my eventual solution.

Comment: Cheers. That's a lot clearer then the first 5 paragraphs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this working for you? I used anchor in cypress document to test.

```
describe('Test anchor link', function(){
  it('test', function(){
    let anchorlink = '';
    let url = 'https://docs.cypress.io/guides/overview/why-cypress.html#Who-uses-Cypress';
    cy.visit(url);
    cy.get('#Cypress-ecosystem > a').then(($anchorlink)=>{
      anchorlink = $anchorlink.prop('href');
      console.log(anchorlink);
    })
});
});
```

The full url is printed in console.
[image]

You can use it later.

Comment: thanks for your solution. I will edit yours when I get into the office to include the solution I discovered last night.

Comment: @Mr. Mr. If using your solution it will only yield the text but not the full url. After I read your question I thought you need the full url rather than the partial url. Can you please try your solution again?

Comment: I used your solution, but changed `get` to `contains`. It worked exactly as I needed it without needing to use `invoke`. Thank you.

Comment: this is not a solution to get a variable outside of a then function scope (or at least it doesnt work for me)...